# How do I install Catia V5 in Wine?

Tags: 12.04, wine

I try to install Catia V5R19 (or V5R18) using Wine. I have Ubuntu 12.04 with all up dates.

1. Install wine (`sudo apt-get install wine`)
2. In your terminal: `winetricks vcrun2005 vcrun2008`
3. Copy `msdrm.dll` in `.wine/drive_c/windows/system32`
4. Mount Catia ISO and launch `setup.exe`
5. `Error : Wrong parameters`
6. The setup launches, and after validating the installation the screen if frozen

[> See screenshot <](http://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/427705Capturedu20120625165640.png)

Any advice ? Solution ? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer :

**Mount the ISO with GMOUNTISO and the installation won't crash :)**